# Is there a way to move plugins in django-cms from one page to another?

Tags: django, plugins, django-cms

I have had a closer look into django-cms. It seems there is no way to manage plugins page-independently.

I would love to have an admin page to move, copy, edit and categorize the plugins without having to create new ones for each page.

What could be an appropriate way to implement this, e.g. creating a new cmsplugin?

Answer (score 1):

We have something like this in mind... and we will cal it presets.

the idea is as follows:

You can create a plugin preset out of an existing plugin and it will be saved in the plugin preset admin.

then you can just drag and drop from the sidebar into the page from a list of such presets.

This still needs implementation though.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. Is "we" the creators of django-cms?
I assume the admin pages would contain functionality for adding/removing plugins to existing presets. Are there any resources/repo to follow yet?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're after, but you can copy a whole page (including it's plugins) from the page list. Doesn't help if you wanted to collect the plugins from two different pages, but I just had to do that to recover a page that wouldn't show any placeholders after publishing.